# What does "Tuppence a bag" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

From the *Feed the birds* song in Mary Poppins. The lyrics include the phrase *Tuppence a bag*. What does this mean?

Comment: "Tuppence" = "two pence" = "two British pennies." The song is about buying 2¢ bags of birdseed to feed park pigeons and sparrows.

Answer (score 7):

"Tuppence" is another word for two pence, an early form of British currency. It can also mean "hardly anything" or "worthless".

The phrase *Tuppence a bag* is an advertisement by the woman in the song. She is offering a bag (of bird food) in exchange for two pence. The soulful nature of a humble character, offering a very humble product, for a very low price, is emphasized by the humble "everyman" word; it's not something a "posh" character of the day would often need to say.

Two old pence (GBX) is worth 1/120 of an old pound sterling; in today's money you could think of it as say 4 Australian cents.

Comment: In some English dialects, "tuppence" also has the colloquial meaning of almost nothing, or worthless: "I wouldn't give you tuppence for that coat.", and many other variations.

Comment: More precisely, *pence* is an alternate plural of *penny*, usually reserved  for values as opposed to coins: "He laid six pennies on the counter" means six individual 1-penny coins, "He laid sixpence on the counter" means coins whose total value was that of six pennies.

Comment: The reference is to pre-decimal British currency, in which tuppence was 1/120 of a pound sterling. The setting of *Mary Poppins* being Edwardian London, I reckon that tuppence then had approximately the same purchasing power as one US dollar (spent in the US) today. And that is what I would expect to spend on an idle purchase of that ilk.

Comment: @Cargill Not only in dialect, surely? It is a perfectly mainstream idiom.

Comment: @StoneyB Sadly, although with new (post 1971) currency, the word *pence* remains - fifty pence etc. - the old forms of *tuppence*, *thruppence*, and *sixpence* no longer have any resonance When it was 20 shillings to the pound and 12 pence to the shilling a *sixpence* (little silver coin, which grandma used to give if you were a good boy or girl) and the beautiful little twelve-sided [*thruppeny bits*](http://www.ebay.co.uk/bhp/threepenny-bit) were respectively half and a quarter of a shilling. My own grandchildren expect rather more than six pence!

Comment: @WS2: I expect the tuppence idiom is not used at all in USA English or Canadian English ... don't know about South Africa, and it is certainly fading from use in Australia and New Zealand (50 years after the switch to decimal currency). So I'm using "dialect" as a pretty broad brush here, and am not referring to Tristan da Cunha, etc.

Comment: Phrases like 'turn on a sixpence' and 'my tuppence worth' is still occasionally heard in Melbourne; obviously, the latter is more commonly rendered as 'my two-cents worth' or similar, but I think 'tuppence' rolls of the tongue better.